# How to put a link passing variable inside php echo

Tags: php, variables, url

I have a link that passes variable to another page but I want to display that link only on some condition so how to place it inside `php` code.

```
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id; ?>">Product</a> 

<?php
echo '<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id; ?>">Product</a>';
?>
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: What's the condition?

Comment: `If ($user==$username)  {`  i.e, user matches session user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, put your anchor link in `if` condition:

```
<?php
if (YOUR_CONDITION_HERE) {
  echo '<a href="page2.php?Id='.$Id.'">Product</a>';
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
if (YOUR_CONDITION_HERE) {
?>
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id;?>">Product</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Above condition will display your link only when your condition is `TRUE`.

Otherwise, it will hide.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line is incorrect why are you opening your php tags again while you're in a echo ?

Please try the following :

```
<?php
 echo '<a href="page2.php?Id='.$Id.'">Product</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your echo field should be.

```
<a href="page2.php?Id=<?php echo $Id; ?>">Product</a> 

<?php
echo '<a href="page2.php?Id='.$Id.'">Product</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to print echo inside3 echo so u hv to do this way!

```
<?php
echo '<a href="page2.php?Id="'.$Id.'" ">Product</a>';
?>
```